# How to prevent going back to the previous activity?

Tags: android, back, back-stack, activity-stack

When the BACK button is pressed on the phone, I want to prevent a specific activity from returning to its previous one.

Specifically, I have login and sign up screens, both start a new activity called `HomeScreen` when successful login/signup occurs. Once HomeScreen is started, I want to prevent the users from being able to return to the login or sign up screens by pressing the BACK key.

I tried using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`, but since the application has Facebook integration, when the 'Login with Facebook' is used, Facebook should return to the initial login screen, therefore I should keep a history of these activities.

I thought of overriding the behaviour of the BACK button on `HomeScreen` to directly finish an application when the button is pressed and I used

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

but that also does not work.

Comment: Just to clarify, you trying to capture back behavior for everyone except facebook?

Comment: In some sense yes, but actually what I want is after a successful login occurs and HomeScreen opens, user should not be able to go back to the login screen by pressing BACK button. Just like Twitter or Foursquare for example, once we log in to those apps, we do not see login page until we log off (even if we press BACK after logging in).

Answer (score 383, accepted):

My suggestion would be to finish the activity that you don't want the users to go back to. For instance, in your sign in activity, right after you call `startActivity`, call `finish()`. When the users hit the back button, they will not be able to go to the sign in activity because it has been killed off the stack.

Comment: What if I would like the thread in the previous activity to remain running?

Comment: You wouldn't want to go with my approach then. Calling finish() is going to kill the activity. Could you start your process that you want to run in the activity that you're going to?

Comment: Note: if you call `finish` during a shared transition you may get a bleed through of the previous activity. e.g., if you have `HomeActivity` -> `IntermediateActivity` -> `FinalActivity`, and you call `finish()` in the `IntermediateActivity` immediately after starting the `FinalActivity` you'll see the `HomeActivity` for a brief moment.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch Do you know any solution for that specific case?

Answer (score 113):

Following solution can be pretty useful in the usual login / main activity scenario or implementing a blocking screen.

To minimize the app rather than going back to previous activity, you can override `onBackPressed()` like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

`moveTaskToBack(boolean nonRoot)` leaves your back stack as it is, just puts your task (all activities) in background. **Same as if user pressed Home button**.

Parameter `boolean nonRoot` - If false then this only works if the activity is the root of a task; if true it will work for any activity in a task.

Comment: Perfect for a login screen because it keeps the history intact.

Comment: Thanks you, I tried to find this for about three days. 
Because of android:noHistory="true" flag for Activity don't work as expected (noHistory flag recreates activity after minimization) and finish() sometimes don't worked for me, but why I still don't understood.

Answer (score 40):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but it sounds like it should be possible, and it also sounds like you're already on the right track.

Here are a few links that might help:

[Disable back button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android)

```
  MyActivity.java =>
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

       return;
    }
```

[How can I disable 'go back' to some activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376708/how-can-i-disable-go-back-to-some-activity)

```
  AndroidManifest.xml =>
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:noHistory="true"/>
```

Comment: I cannot use the noHistory option because of the Facebook issue which I tried to explain in my question and also one of the comments. But the thing with the BACK button is not disabling it, but making it exit the whole application like `System.exit(0)` is called (I know it is not the best practive, but I just wanted to give an example).

Comment: Thanks this worked great. Only suggestion I'd make here would be, no need for return. Just remove super.onBackPressed();and leave the method blank. That works fine as well

Answer (score 24):

There are two solutions for your case, activity A starts activity B, but you do not want to back to activity A in activity B.

**1. Removed previous activity A from back stack.**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(activityA.this, activityB.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); // Destroy activity A and not exist in Back stack
```

**2. Disabled go back button action in activity B.**

*There are two ways to prevent go back event as below,*

1) Recommend approach

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

2）Override onKeyDown method

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Hope that it is useful, but still depends on your situations.

Comment: Is it not bad user experience to disable the onBackPressed()?

Comment: It totally depends on what you are trying to make, in app functionility needs this then go for it.

Comment: It's amazing how I completely forgot about the first method using`finish()`. Unnecessarily overthought with `nohistory` attribute, intent flags, parent activity manifest tags, etc! Silly, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 14):

Since there are already many great solutions suggested, ill try to give a more dipictive explanation.

> How to **skip** going back to the previous activity?

Remove the previous Activity from Backstack. Simple

> How to remove the previous Activity from Backstack?

Call `finish()` method

### The Normal Flow:

[image]
All the activities are stored in a Stack known as Backstack.
When you start a new Activity(`startActivity(...)`) then the new Activity is pushed to top of the stack and when you press back button the Activity is popped from the stack.
**One key point** to note is that when the back button is pressed then `finish();` method is called internally. This is the default behavior of onBackPressed() method.

#### So if you want to skip Activity B?

> ie A<--- C

Just add `finish();` method after your `startActvity(...)` in the Activity B

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, C.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

[image]

Comment: this is partial solution, `context` doesn't have `finish()`

Comment: Activity has finish() method.

Answer (score 7):

`finish()` gives you method to close current Activity not whole application. And you better don't try to look for methods to kill application. Little advice.

Have you tried conjunction of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`? Remember to use this flags in `Intent` starting activity!

Comment: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` prevents my LoginScreen to capture Facebook's callback when Login with Facebook is used. Because once the focus goes out of the LoginScreen it cannot be resumed (since there is no history). But I haven't tried it with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS`, I'll check it, thanks!

Comment: also thanks about the `finish()` method, I did not know about it.

Answer (score 4):

Put `finish()` just after

```
Intent i = new Intent(Summary1.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: This is basically what the accepted answer from four years prior said.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to go back to all the activities on your application, you can use

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Learn more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 3):

paulsm4's answer is the correct one. If in `onBackPressed()` you just return, it will disable the back button. However, I think a better approach given your use case is to flip the activity logic, i.e. make your home activity the main one, check if the user is signed in there, if not, start the sign in activity. The reason is that if you override the back button in your main activity, most users will be confused when they press back and your app does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

**This method is working fine**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Profile.this, MainActivity.class); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

When you create `onBackPressed()` just remove `super.onBackPressed();`and that should work

Answer (score 2):

Just override the onKeyDown method and check if the back button was pressed.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
    {
        //Back buttons was pressed, do whatever logic you want
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
finish();
```

immediately after
    ActivityStart
to stop the activity preventing any way of going back to it. 
Then add

```
onCreate(){
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    ...
}
```

to the activity you are starting.

Answer (score 1):

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <activity 
      android:name=".welcome.SplashActivity"
      android:noHistory="true" // just add this line
      android:exported="true">  

 </activity>
```