# Back Stack maintain - android

Tags: android

I developed one application in android.It works perfectly but if i press back button then it will show all the previous activities like currently login,previous login etc. means all the things. How this remove from?

Comment: Try this: finish() current activity while going to next activity.

Comment: This link will help you to how to maintain stack(not session) in application:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Preventing going back to the previous activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631095/android-preventing-going-back-to-the-previous-activity)

Answer (score 1):

Use `finish()` after Intent calling for next activity.

for example..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

It open next activity and remove activity from BackStackTrace.

Answer (score 0):

call finish() before starting the next activity

Comment: okay. i will try it. firstly i was tried it. but not working. so... but now i will also try this time.thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

call `finish()` after Intent calling for next activity.

/

Providing Proper Back Navigation

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

For example:

```
<application ... >
    ...
    <!-- The main/home activity (it has no parent activity) -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" ...>
        ...
    </activity>
    <!-- A child of the main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```