# How to create display multiple layouts in onCreateView method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to create an intro slider screen using fragments and `ViewPager`. I want to display multiple layouts in `onCreateView` method but don't know how to do it.

Any help please?

**Main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ViewPager pager;
    public The_fragment_adapter the_fragment_adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        the_fragment_adapter = new The_fragment_adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(the_fragment_adapter);
    }
}
```

**Fragment Class**

```
public class The_fragment extends Fragment {

    public The_fragment(){
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View my_view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.theui,container,false);
        return my_view;
    }
}
```

**Adapter View**

```
public class The_fragment_adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public int[] the_layouts = {R.layout.page1,R.layout.page2};

    public The_fragment_adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new The_fragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return the_layouts.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by multiple layouts?

Comment: Right now,In onCreateView method only one layout is being displayed i.e theui but i want to display 2 different layouts and make a slider of those two layouts.

Answer (score 0):

A `ViewPager` is for paging multiple fragments, not layouts. The `getItem()` method should return the fragment you want for the position you want.

Create a second fragment with the layout you want:

```
public Fragment The_second_fragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View my_view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2,container,false);
        return my_view;
    }
}
```

Then change your adapter methods:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch 0:
        return new The_fragment();
    switch 1:
        return new The_second_fragment();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

See the excellent [tutorial in the Android Developer's Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html). And, in the future if you follow the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) you are more likely to get a better answer as other programmers will be able to understand your code more easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Well that's done.Now i just want to kill those fragments after using them.I am trying to use finish(); method but that's not working.

Comment: You don't need to kill the fragments manually. They will be killed when your activity is destroyed.

Comment: I tried to put another activity and access it through the button on the second fragment.When i am on that activity and pressses the back button,it takes me back to the fragments

Comment: Glad you got the multiple fragments working! I hope you can use one of the solutions [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631095/android-preventing-going-back-to-the-previous-activity) to solve your second question. Good luck!