# How do I check if another activity is on the stack?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-adt, android-4.4-kitkat

I am creating an android app with Eclipse and currently when I press back until the stack is empty(using NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)), it exits the application.  However, I was wondering how I could check if the stack is empty or not so that when it is empty, I could go to the main menu instead of exiting the application.  Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are looking for this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(getIntent().hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)) {
        //this is the last activity on stack
        doSomethingSpecial();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

maybe also interesting:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970728/how-to-check-if-activity-is-still-in-the-stack)

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376708/how-can-i-disable-go-back-to-some-activity)